# Reversing of an Arabic string resulting from abcpdf .net

Tags: c#

I have used abcpdf.net to convert an Arabic pdf through `read(pdfpath)` and `gettext()` functions, the resulted text (string) looks like these it's unreadable as Arabic is an RTL language. My question is now I have to reverse the Arabic parts of the string to make it readable but I don't know how can I do that. How can I extract the Arabic part only and then reverse it?

I am using C#, and here is a sample of the extracted string from my PDF when using abcpdf .net library:

```
0.00
KCCUSER1
 6:17:19PM28/10/2010ةعابطلا خيرات

(200) لوادتملا زكارمو تاكرح

ةصاقملل ةيتيوكلا ةكرشلا

28/10/2010

RBKPI012

لمعلا خيرات

عمجم/ ح - 88لجلا عيبلل افيا ةيلودلا ةيلاملا تاراشتسلا ةكرش  -  65646

C023

يحاتتفلا ديصرلا
```

Comment: It is the job of the app that displays the text to properly render the string.  It needs to be RTL aware.  You haven't said what app you use to look at it.

Answer (score 2):

```
private string Convert(string source)
{
    string arabicWord = string.Empty;
    StringBuilder sbDestination = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (var ch in source)
    {
        if (IsArabic(ch))
            arabicWord += ch;
        else
        {
            if (arabicWord != string.Empty)
                sbDestination.Append(Reverse(arabicWord));

            sbDestination.Append(ch);
            arabicWord = string.Empty;
        }
    }

    // if the last word was arabic    
    if (arabicWord != string.Empty)
        sbDestination.Append(Reverse(arabicWord));

    return sbDestination.ToString();
}
```

IsArabic method from [here](http://www.makhaly.net/Blog.aspx?MessageId=13)

```
private bool IsArabic(char character)
{
    if (character >= 0x600 && character <= 0x6ff)
        return true;

    if (character >= 0x750 && character <= 0x77f)
        return true;

    if (character >= 0xfb50 && character <= 0xfc3f)
        return true;

    if (character >= 0xfe70 && character <= 0xfefc)
        return true;

    return false;
}

// Reverse the characters of string
string Reverse(string source)
{
    return new string(source.ToCharArray().Reverse().ToArray());
}
```

Good luck!